# The simplest way to draw points on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, 2d, draw

in my app I have 49 points with x,y and I wnat to display them on the screen. I've seen a lot of library that can help me (core plot, s7graphview, etc.). But since I'm doing very basic stuff (just draw points), what is the simplest way do to that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basic core graphics. Plenty of examples on the developer.apple.com site or just google for Core Graphics iPhone Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Quartz2d method to draw a small circle:

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect
```